# What does mov 0x40(%eax),%eax mean?

Tags: iphone, ios, gdb

What does

```
0x01b55ee2  <+0014>  mov    0x40(%eax),%eax
```

mean? How should I interpret 0x40(), as I am having a problem with my code crashing in that location. The contents of the %eax register is 0.

Comment: There are many different styles of assembly language, but the above is common among several microprocessor lines.  It's a "move" (data copying) instruction.  There are two operands.  The right operand is simple -- register eax.  The left operand is the storage location addressed by (the value in register eax added to the constant 0x40).  I'm a little fuzzy as to whether this is moving left or right.  If eax is zero then you're dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: Note that this statement is essentially what you'd get following a linked list.  But (if this is so) the last link pointer it loaded was null, so it's fallen off the end of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you're looking at treats `%eax + 0x40` as an address, and moves 32 bits from that address to `%eax`. If `%eax` is zero, this means that what you're dealing with is basically a NULL pointer dereference.